# Can't click accessibilityservice button while holding the screen

Tags: android, accessibilityservice, android-touch-event

I followed this [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/developing-android-a11y-service#0) to learn how to develop accessibility service in android.

Everything works fine, but when I touch and hold the screen, the button in the service can't get any touch event.

Any solution to this problem? So that I click the buttons while holding the screen.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.